# multiprocessing [concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor] not calling function correctly

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

Hello fellow programmers, I'm new to multiprocessing. I've watched this guide on multiprocessing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso&t=2367s and am trying to make the code work. Basically what this does is read a bunch of images and save them to the `processed` folder.

link to zip (130MB): https://ufile.io/kt420x7q

The whole code:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

parent_path = Path(__file__).parent
output_path = parent_path.joinpath('processed')

def process_image(img_name):
    img = Image.open(img_name)
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(15))
    img.thumbnail(size)
    img.save(f'{output_path.joinpath(img_name)}')
    print(f'{img_name} was processed...')

def main():
    img_names = [
        'photo-1532009324734-20a7a5813719.jpg',
        'photo-1524429656589-6633a470097c.jpg',
        'photo-1530224264768-7ff8c1789d79.jpg',
        'photo-1541698444083-023c97d3f4b6.jpg',
        'photo-1522364723953-452d3431c267.jpg',
        'photo-1513938709626-033611b8cc03.jpg',
        'photo-1493976040374-85c8e12f0c0e.jpg',
        'photo-1504198453319-5ce911bafcde.jpg',
        'photo-1530122037265-a5f1f91d3b99.jpg',
        'photo-1516972810927-80185027ca84.jpg',
        'photo-1550439062-609e1531270e.jpg']

    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    size = (1200, 1200)

##     # Normal Loop Function
##    for img_name in img_names:
##        img = Image.open(img_name)
##        img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(15))
##        img.thumbnail(size)
##        img.save(f'{output_path.joinpath(img_name)}')
##        print(f'{img_name} was processed...')

    # Multiprocessing Function
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(process_image, img_names)

    t2 = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

##input()
```

As you can see there is a `Normal Loop Function` and a `Multiprocessing Function`. The `MP-function` is supposed to do the exact same thing as the `Normal Loop Function` but it seems to not execute `process_image` function properly.

When I run:

```
 # Normal Loop Function
for img_name in img_names:
    img = Image.open(img_name)
    img = img.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(15))
    img.thumbnail(size)
    img.save(f'{output_path.joinpath(img_name)}')
    print(f'{img_name} was processed...')
```

it works as intended printing the progress and saving the images to `processed` folder:

```
photo-1532009324734-20a7a5813719.jpg was processed...
photo-1524429656589-6633a470097c.jpg was processed...
photo-1530224264768-7ff8c1789d79.jpg was processed...
photo-1541698444083-023c97d3f4b6.jpg was processed...
photo-1522364723953-452d3431c267.jpg was processed...
photo-1513938709626-033611b8cc03.jpg was processed...
photo-1493976040374-85c8e12f0c0e.jpg was processed...
photo-1504198453319-5ce911bafcde.jpg was processed...
photo-1530122037265-a5f1f91d3b99.jpg was processed...
photo-1516972810927-80185027ca84.jpg was processed...
photo-1550439062-609e1531270e.jpg was processed...
Finished in 11.8887978 seconds
```

But when I try to run the `MP-Function`:

```
# Multiprocessing Function
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process_image, img_names)
```

the output is:

```
Finished in 3.8939473 seconds
```

In this case the progress is not printed at all nor are the images saved to the `processed` folder. This output comes from executing the code in IDLE. Since IDLE seems to have problems with multiprocessing I also tried to execute the script by running it from the windows terminal. In this case there is no output and the process keeps running indefinitely.

Comment: What does the map call return? From the docs: __If a func call raises an exception, then that exception will be raised when its value is retrieved from the iterator__.

Comment: How can I check what the map call returns?

Comment: if you put: `result = executor.map(process_image, img_names)` result will be a generator, then simply loop through result: `for res in result: print(res)` and if an error has been raised in the function it will now be raised in the main program